# strtotime function doesnot support a specific date format

Tags: php, strtotime

I am using strtotime function with a specific date format but it's not working yet.

```
$gDate='30/04/2014';
echo strtotime($gDate);
```

Comment: echo strtotime('2014/04/03); this will work

Comment: use strftime php.net/strftime

Answer (score 0):

And thats the reason you should use `DateTime` class in PHP

`strtotime()` returns long UNIX timestamp, in DateTime its `getTimestamp()`

```
$gDate='30/04/2014';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $gDate);
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 0):

date in your format

```
    $gDate='30/04/2014';
```

change date format for make it usable by strtotime function

```
    $date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $gDate);
```

echo forate to check the really format
    echo $mydate = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');

strtotime function on your given date

```
    echo $mystr = strtotime($mydate);
```

/*-strtotime is only works on "Y-m-d" format
 *
 * -in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats;
 * -if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed
 * -If the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed
 *
 *
 * -To avoid potential errors, you should YYYY-MM-DD
 * */